# custom input in Joomla 2.5 article

Tags: joomla2.5, article

I'm new in stack overflow and Joomla. I am building a template and I want to add a custom input like color in Joomla 2.5 article from the admin side. but I could not find any suitable option for doing this. 
I tried modifying the default.xml for article, but no help.
Please assist me.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add your field in default.xml and print it in edit.php file